# Why it is possible to generate an array of dynamic size in C?

Tags: c, arrays, constants

I wrote the following c - codesnippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int size){
    int array[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%d ", array[i]);

    }
}

int main(){
    int array_size;
    scanf("%d",&array_size);
    function(array_size);

    return 0;

}
```

Why it is possible to generate an array of dynamic size this way. Normally I would use malloc, but this works as well. Why it is allowed to use the non constant variable size for the size of an array?

Comment: You did not initialize the array members. The compiler may ignore/remove it al together. It is called _undefined behavior_.

Comment: This is probably resolved very similar to the way the `alloca()` function works. Allocating the array would be simply a matter of adjusting the current stack pointer to make space for the dynamic-sized array. Deallocation occurs automatically at function exit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what is known as a **"*Variable-length array*".**

Variable-length automatic arrays have been supported since C99

They are declared like a normal array, but length is not constant and storage is allocated at the point of declaration.

More on this can be found @ [gcc.gnu.org](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)

Comment: But... VLA are optional since C11. And for example Microsoft still do not support them (but AFAIK also fails to correctly declare the required compilation constant). So it is supported by gcc and clang but if you want to be super safe you should still be cautious...

Answer (score 3):

> Why it is possible to generate an array of dynamic size this way ?

No, This

```
int array[size]; /* this doesn't get stored in heap section */
```

where `size` is a run time integer constant, is **not a dynamic array**, it's called [Variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) & it was introduced in [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99). **Dynamic array** created only by calling either `malloc()` or `calloc()` which gets the address from **heap** section of primary memory.

> Why it is allowed to use the non constant variable size for the size
>   of an array?

Yes, `C99` onwards `VLA` can have `size` as **non-constant** variable. But you can't change(resized) the size of `VLA` once declared unlike dynamic array(can use `realloc()`).